# How to identify latest application build folder based on folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I am struggling to find an intelligent way to determine the latest build folder that is among a number of other folders and I hope someone can point me in the correct direction.

**Main Application Install Path:**
C:\Program Files\ABC

**Subfolders:**

- MiscFolder01
- MiscFolder02
- AppName 5.0
- AppName 5.0.0.0
- AppName 5.0.1.0
- AppName 5.0.2.0

The user could have any one of the "AppName 5.* " folders installed. There could be a possibility to have any combination of the "AppName 5.* " folders as well if an older build was not properly uninstalled prior to installing a later build.

So I need to identify the latest build installed based on the folder name and set that to a variable "LATEST_BUILD".

Example #1: User has "App Name 5.0", "App Name 5.0.0.0" and "App Name 5.0.2.0" installed, but since "App Name 5.0.2.0" is the latest, I need to set "App Name 5.0.2.0" to variable %LATEST_BUILD%

I hope this makes sense to you all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably solve this task using the following code (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=C:\Program Files\ABC" & rem // (root directory)
set "_NAME=AppName"              & rem // (folder name prefix)

rem // Initialise variables:
set /A "HIGHEST=0" & set "LATEST="
rem // Loop through potentionally matching folders:
for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:D "%_ROOT%\%_NAME% *"') do (
    rem // Split off last space-separated name portion:
    set "FOLDER=%%F" & set "NUMBER="
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%H in ("!FOLDER: =" "!") do (if not defined NUMBER endlocal) & set "NUMBER=%%~H"
    rem // Filter for name portions consisting of numerals and dots only:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%E in ('echo("!NUMBER!" ^| findstr "\"[0-9\.]*\""') do (
        endlocal
        rem // Extract individual version numbers (four at most):
        for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. eol=." %%A in ("%%E.0.0.0.0") do (
            rem /* Compute a number out of the individual version numbers;
            rem    note that none of them must have more than two digits: */
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set /A "CURRENT=((%%A*100+%%B)*100+%%C)*100+%%D"
            rem // Compare the current number with the stored greatest one:
            if !CURRENT! gtr !HIGHEST! (
                rem // Store the current number as the greatest one in case it is such:
                for /F %%H in ("!CURRENT!") do endlocal & set /A "HIGHEST=%%H"
                rem // Store the folder name correlating with the current number:
                set "LATEST=%%F"
            ) else endlocal
        )
    )
)
rem // Return the resulting folder name:
echo Found folder name: %LATEST%
echo Latest version:    %NUMBER%
echo Comparison number: %HIGHEST%

endlocal
exit /B
```

This can process folder names with up to four individual version numbers (like `5.0.2.0`), each of which may consist of two decimal figures at most.

Comment: I actually didn't even think about the two decimal figure possibility until you posted this solution. This will do exactly what I am looking for after I added a small tweak to pass the detected variables beyond the final "end local" command. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is by using an `FOR` loop along with `dir /b` to get all the folder names. From there we can use a basic greater then statement to compare all the numbers that come after the *BuildFolderName*.

**Main.Bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Configuration (Directory Path) & (BuildFolderName)
set "InstallPath=C:\Program Files\ABC"
set "BuildFolderName=AppName"
CD %InstallPath%

Rem | Get Folder "AppName*" to String
set "Latest=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b^| find /I "%BuildFolderName%"') do (

    Rem | Extract Numbers From String
    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%B in ('Echo %%A') do (

        Rem | Find Largest Number
        Set "NUM=%%C"
        if !NUM! GTR !MAX! set "Latest=%BuildFolderName% !NUM!"
    )
)

Rem | Here Is The Latest (Largest) File
Echo Your Latest Update Is: %Latest%

pause
goto :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately when I posted the question, I did not take into consideration the fact that I could run into two decimal places in the build codes. This solution worked as well and was a bit simpler if I only needed one decimal place. Thanks for the support....